# Troubleshooting OpenGL ES 1.1 textures on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, textures

I'm trying to draw a texture into an offscreen framebuffer, and its renderbuffer always ends up completely blank (black). The weird thing is, I know the context is set up, and I'm checking for errors using glCheckFramebufferStatusOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES) and glGetError(), but neither function says anything is wrong. Are there any other error-checking functions I can call which might shed some light on what's happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Difficult to give you a precise answer without more information. Perhaps could you post some code about your setup and usage of the render buffer?

In the meantime, here is some info about how to properly setup an offscreen framebuffer:

```
// Remember the FBO being used for the display framebuffer
glGetIntegerv(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_BINDING_OES, (GLint *)&SystemFBO);

// Create the texture and the FBO for offscreen frame buffer
glGenTextures(1, &ResultTexture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, ResultTexture);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
glGenFramebuffersOES(1, &ResultFBO);
glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, ResultFBO);
glFramebufferTexture2DOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_OES, GL_TEXTURE_2D, ResultTexture, 0);

glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, ResultFBO);

// do your rendering to offscreen framebuffer
...

// restore original frame buffer object
glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, SystemFBO);

// use ResultTexture as usual
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, ResultTexture);
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks. I thought at the time that the problem was some internal OpenGL error that wasn't being reported by either glGetError() or glCheckFramebufferStatusOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES), but it was just me misusing OpenGL. I had called glColor4f(0, 0, 0, 0) at a previous point in the program, so when I drew the textures, it drew with alpha=0. I guess this is an example of where reading the manual first would have saved some time...